# How to produce a single *.d.ts or multiple with relative path

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs, ts-loader

#### Problem

[It only infects typescript library creators]

if the code base contains absolute paths (by configuring `tsconfig.json` and webpack), then the typescript compiler will generate all the d.ts files with the same absolute paths that are useless because my lib consumers can't do a thing with them.

---

#### Workarounds

Every library that **I saw** are doing one of the following:

1. creating their own single-file.d.ts file manually
2. using relative path in their code base so the output d.ts files also contain relative paths.

***Clearly, both alternatives suck.***

---

#### Other solution that I thought about

1. creating a single d.ts file (there will be no imports).

I couldn't find a working library for that.

2. not sure if it's possible: before running ts-loader, we need to run a magic babel-plugin to transform every absolute path to a relative by looking in the webpack-resolve-module section in webpack.config file.

---

#### My current status

I created a library that generates broken d.ts files with absolute paths:

https://github.com/stavalfi/lerna-yarn-workspaces-example/tree/master/packages/x-core

index.ts:

```
import { z, x } from 'shalom'     // problem
export default function awesomeFn(y: number): x {
  return z(1)
}

export { z, x } from './shalom' . // not a problem
```

generated index.d.ts:

```
import { x } from './shalom';     /// GOOD - becuase I used relative
export default function awesomeFn(y: number): x;
export { z, x } from 'shalom';    /// BAD - because I used absolute
//# sourceMappingURL=index.d.ts.map .
```

---

## Question

Is there any sort of solution/workaround that is not stop using an absolute path or creating my own single.d.ts file manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If any typescript library creator still has this problem, I created a Webpack loader for babel-plugin-module-resolver, which converts absolute paths to relative paths:
https://github.com/stavalfi/babel-plugin-module-resolver-loader

It also solved the problem of `*.d.ts` files with absolute paths by converting them to relative paths.

---

You will probably want to subscribe to/read this thread for additional workarounds:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15479